# MVC DropDownList setting default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-select

```
var userColor = db.userColor;
foreach(var x in userColor){
    var correspondingDropDownValue = from m in db.user
                                     where m.UserID == x.UserID
                                     select m;

 ViewData["dropDown_Color"] = correspondingDropDownValue.Select(j => new SelectListItem { Text = j.ListOfValue, Value = j.ListOfValue }).ToList();
}
```

In this db.userColor table has another column known as db.userColor.default which carry a value that to be used as the default value. How can I modify the code above to set the selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` to determine which should be selected by default:

```
ViewData["dropDown_Color"] = correspondingDropDownValue.Select(j => new SelectListItem { Text = j.ListOfValue, Value = j.ListOfValue, Selected = j.ListOfValue == j.userColor.default }).ToList();
```

Not being able to see your schema, I'm guessing where `userColor.default` is, but you can update the logic as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below code to set property 

 List<LimitType> objLimitTypeList = new List<LimitType>();

        LimitType objLimitType = new LimitType();
        objLimitType.WithinLimitCode = 0;
        objLimitType.WithinLimitName = "Within Limit";
        objLimitTypeList.Add(objLimitType);

        LimitType objLimitTypeN = new LimitType();
        objLimitTypeN.WithinLimitCode = 1;
        objLimitTypeN.WithinLimitName = "Over Limit";
        objLimitTypeList.Add(objLimitTypeN);

        if (BtnAct.ToLower() == "add")
        {
            ViewBag.WithinLimit = new SelectList(objLimitTypeList, "WithinLimitCode", "WithinLimitName");
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsWithinLimit.ToLower() == "y")
                ViewBag.WithinLimit = new SelectList(objLimitTypeList, "WithinLimitCode", "WithinLimitName", 0);
            else
                ViewBag.WithinLimit = new SelectList(objLimitTypeList, "WithinLimitCode", "WithinLimitName", 1);

        }
```